# Using a For to list all files and use them as variables

Tags: batch-file

Right now my script works with this file setting the path to the txt files I need to execute.

Is there a way to improve the script so it reads all the files in the servers folder and uses them instead of %s1%,%s2%, etc on the second FOR?

The script

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%c in (servers\list.txt) do (
    %%c
)
for %%a in (%s1% %s2% %s3%) do (
    call :start %%a
)
```

File list:

```
set s1=servers\xxx.txt
set s2=servers\yyy.txt
set s3=servers\zzz.txt
```

Servers folder contains the list.txt and files xxx.txt, yyy.txt, zzz.txt, etc.

xxx.txt, yyy.txt files have the next format:

```
set server=192.168.0.0
set user=user
...
```

Comment: `For %%A In ("servers\*.txt") Do Call :start "%%A"`

Comment: `for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("servers\list.txt") do call :start %%J`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to nest your `for` loops, not execute one after the other:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%l in (list.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (%%l) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%c in (%%a) do %%c
    ECHO !server!,!dbname!,!dbuser!,!dbpass!
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /F "tokens=*" %%c in (q45322067.txt) do (
    %%c
)
for /F "tokens=2delims== " %%a in (q45322067.txt) do (
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ('set %%a') DO IF /i "%%b"=="%%a" ECHO call :start %%c
)
ECHO -------------------------------
for /F "tokens=3delims== " %%a in (q45322067.txt) do (
  ECHO call :start %%a
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q45322067.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Here's a couple of ways, depending on whether or not you actually need to load `s?` or you have some reason to use `s?` as an intermediate variable.